# Salesforce MVP Class of 2024 Nominations Are Open

Tags: discussion, mvp

You can now nominate who you believe should become Salesforce MVP in 2024.

- Find [more information](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/mvp/) about the MVP programme
- Or go directly to the [nomination page](https://nominations.salesforcemvps.com/s/start?language=en_US)

Many here on SFSE are already MVPs, and we have also a number of rising stars who are yet to become an MVP. It might be since they did not yet meet the criteria (e.g. due to being a Salesforce employee). Look around you and nominate your MVP candidate already today.